# Getting failed to start session when installing Cinnamon desktop

Tags: cinnamon

I am getting a strange issue when attempting to install Cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS version. I have tried installing this Desktop environment using two methods.

The first one is to install via `tasksel` and the other one is to install it using the following commands:

```
apt-get install cinnamon -y

apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment -y
```

Yet the issue is still the same. I dropped into shell and checked the privileges given to `/usr/bin/cinnamon-session-cinnamon` but they were correct.

What else should I check?

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Eef.png)

Comment: AFAIK a session can't be started directly - it needs an X server. How you proceed depends on your intent - do you want to login customarily via a GUI display manager, or start GUI sessions on an ad hoc basis from the server command line?

Comment: @steeldriver I thought that X server would have been installed directly. Yeah i want to login customarily.

Comment: It's almost certainly been *installed* - you will *probably* find that the default display manager (lightdm in the case of cinnamon I think) has also been installed, and will start automatically when you reboot (or if you isolate the graphical target with `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`)

Comment: @steeldriver but why is session failing to start then? I read up several places but it still isn't loading.